# Custom UIScrollView class not initializing IBOutlets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've recently dived into the world of Swift 3 and Xcode 8 and have been working on a simple game to learn as much as possible but I have run into an issue where my custom class is crashing when I segue into it because the IBOutlets which I dragged into it are nil.

I am using `StoryBoard` and `AutoLayout` and have dragged several fields into my class `statistics:UIScrollView` from the storyboard.

```
class StatisticsView: UIScrollView, sendLabelDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var GamesWonNum: UILabel!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.GamesWonNum = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "GamesWonNum") as! UILabel!
    }

    override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.GamesWonNum, forKey: "GamesWonNum")

    }

    func setLabel(data: String) {
        let temp = Int(data)
        setNumber(num: temp!)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() { }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    func setNumber(num: Int){
        GamesWonNum.text = String(num)
    }
}
```

I have made sure that the statistics class is set as the identifier for the storyboard scrollview. I've done a lot of research into the topic, and I couldn't find a concrete answer on exactly how this works. I found in another post that calling the function `awakefromNib()` will fix the issue and it has, but I want to understand what `awakefromNib()` does and why I cannot simply `init()` the view.

My view Controller hierarchy is as follows:

**MainMenuVC | --Segue--> SettingsVC**

**MainMenyVC | --Segue--> StatisticsVC**

```
class StatisticsVC: UIViewController, sendLabelDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var StatsScrollView: UIScrollView!

    var settingsLabel:String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if UIScreen.main.bounds.height < 600 {
            StatsScrollView.contentSize.height = 700
            print("screensizeif: \(UIScreen.main.bounds.height), \(StatsScrollView.contentSize.height)")
        }else{
            StatsScrollView.contentSize.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
            print("screensizeelse: \(UIScreen.main.bounds.height), \(StatsScrollView.contentSize.height)")
        }
        StatsScrollView.contentSize.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        StatsScrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }

    func setLabel(data: String) {
        settingsLabel = data
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding is that the viewController will init all of its views before going into the `viewdidLoad()` function, so why is `awakefromNib()` necessary and what exactly should I define inside of it. Further, why can't I initialize the class inside `init()`? If I try to set the GamesWon Outlet inside `init()`, the outlet is `nil`.

Its a bit difficult for me to wrap my head around the relationship that exists here between a view controller, the custom scrollview I have, and the outlets being nil. If anyone could clarify I would very much appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to post your code as graphics?

Comment: Sorry about that, corrected.